# Testing $.proxy with mocha, chai, and sinon

Tags: jquery, mocha.js, sinon, chai, sinon-chai

I am trying to write a test that will test function called after an event, but I have this function wrapped in a jquery proxy, and it seems to be throwing my sinon spy off.

the jquery looks like so:

```
this.$modalcontent.on('change', '.js-qty-to-return', $.proxy(this.qtyChanged, this))
```

my test looks like this:

```
it('should trigger qtyChange function', function(done) {
        var proxy = sinon.stub(jQuery, 'proxy');
        $('.js-qty-to-return').trigger('change');
        expect(proxy.calledWith(this.OrderHistoryTable.qtyChanged, this.OrderHistoryTable)).to.be.ok;
        proxy.restore();
        done();
    });
```

I've also tried doing the stub in the before function above the test, I've tried using sinon spy instead of stub, I've tried stubbing the function/method itself as well, I have verified that the function is indeed actually called, it is recieving data from the trigger, and it is processing all the way through as expected, but when I check for a `.called` it always returns false.

I could just be overlooking something simple, any suggestions or ideas are helpful.